# How to turn off screen magnifier?

Tags: display

The screen magnifier has been turned on.  The mouse moves the view around the desktop.  It can't get into applications because mouse-over moves the menu out of the way and closes the applications window.  I have looked into Universal Access but there isn't a magnifier or a choice for turning the magnifier off.  I have 0.4 Loki and it got updates today.

Comment: I have posted as answer. You mean you solved it with Super-minus? If so, you may mark the answer as definitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only magnifier present on the system seems to be the zoom triggered by Super+ and Super- (plus and minus)

Comment: This works, I approve - thank you! Also, it should be mentioned, you need to press *both* Super+ and Super- *at the same time* to initiate it. Pressing each of these buttons alone the respective key will adjust zoom ratio. Zoom out to end the mode, which is what the asker wanted to know. This feature is from great minds.